# Нужны ли кавычки в названии монеты?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, названия

Крымская стратегическая наступательная операция.
Так называется монета в честь событий ВОВ. Кавычить ли?

Comment: Кавычить ВОВ? Да?

Comment: нет, монета называется...Крымская наступательная операция....написано это на оборотной стороне....

Answer (score 1):

1. Считаю, что названия монет нужно брать в кавычки. Здесь можно провести параллель с названиями [орденов и медалей](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/75-kav2), которые обрамляются кавычками:
   орден «За военные заслуги», медаль «За отвагу».

Слово "монета" выступает в этом случае как **родовое**:
монета «Крымская стратегическая наступательная операция»;
монета «Керченско-Эльтигенская десантная операция»;
серия монет «Красная книга».

Главное — не путать названия и обычные словосочетания при письме.
Сравните:
На монете **«Оборона Севастополя»** изображен мемориал «Матрос и солдат».
*Навсегда сохранит наш народ память о героической **обороне Севастополя**...*(И. Сталин)

[Серия монет «Крымские операции»](http://msolkin.ru/crimea-coins/)

2. Вот что пишет [Грамота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F) об аббревиатуре ВОВ.

**Вопрос № 260140**
Скажите, пожалуйста, как пишется аббревиатура " Великая Отечественная война" — ВОВ или ВОв?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
Аббревиатура пишется прописными: ВОВ. Однако надо иметь в виду, что употребление этого сокращения – признак канцелярско-бюрократического языка. Лингвисты называют эту аббревиатуру варварской и рекомендуют всячески избегать ее употребления.

Comment: Римма, комментарий не Вам лично, а в общем. Не понимаю, почему в этом варваризме закрепилась большая буква. Это что – нормы написания аббревиатур? Ведь была же, например, ВКП(б). С детства помню, писали ВОв, чтобы не возвеличивать само понятие войны. Так когда же установили писать всё большими? Два часа ищу, читаю, не могу найти объяснения...

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Поскольку речь идёт о событии, у которого есть название. Точно так же говорят Оборона Москвы или Блокада Ленинграда. Вот если бы был фильм об этой операции, то он бы назывался "Крымская стратегическая наступательная операция".

Comment: получается, рассказывается о каждой монете...в заглавии вот такие вехи ВОВ....ну без кавычек получится, что рассказ о событии....

Comment: Ну если рассказ о монете - то, да, кавычить.